# Write shiny$HTML(...) without tags$head(...) in Shiny

Tags: html, r, shiny, shinydashboard

How can I write this below just using `shiny$HTML` to the code instead of `tags$head(shiny$HTML(...)`?

Ex:

```
tags$head(
HTML("<title> Hell Tattoo Dashboard</title>
<link rel='shortcut icon' href='www/hell.png'></link>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='www/shiny.css'></link>
     <script src='www/shiny.js'></script>"
     )
)
```

works.

I insert the `<head>` tag without `tags$head`:

```
HTML("<head>
<title> Hell Tattoo Dashboard</title>
<link rel='shortcut icon' href='www/hell.png'></link>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='www/shiny.css'></link>
     <script src='www/shiny.js'></script>
</head>"
     )
```

doesn't work.

I want to use `shiny$HTML` tags, just, pure, without `tags$head`. It's possible?

simple shinyApp:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

h <- dashboardHeader(title = "a")

s <- dashboardSidebar()

b <- dashboardBody()

ui <- dashboardPage(h, s, b, skin = "blue")

server <- function(input, output) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Where are you putting this code in your simple shiny example? What exactly "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working fine:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    HTML("<head>
            <title>Hell Tattoo Dashboard</title>
          </head>"
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: result]